# How to make Tiny Planet photo in java web

Tags: javascript

I have to convert 3D photo to tiny planet photo in java or javascript? How can I convert. There is a simple example in Phyton

http://www.richwareham.com//little-planet-projection/ . But I need it in java or javascript.